TYPO3 11.5: Get properties of invalid domain object in Controller action
There are two actions in my Controller, formAction() and sendOrderAction(). The latter should process a domain object Order, which is validated on submitting the formAction. This works as expected. But when the validation fails, I also want to access some properties the object might have in the formAction. But unfortunately, the object is always null when its validation failed (even if I use @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\IgnoreValidation). Is there any other way to access its properties?
/**
 * form action
 *
 * @param Order $order
 * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\IgnoreValidation("order")
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function formAction(Order $order = null): void
{
    // Here, I want to access possible properties of $order, in case the validation failed, for example:
    DebuggerUtility::var_dump($order->getFirstName());
    // Doesn't work, the param $order is always null
}

/**
 * sendOrder action
 *
 * @param Order $order
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function sendOrderAction(Order $order): void
{
    // Do stuff with $order when validation succeeds
}

I also tried accessing the arguments with $this->arguments, but that didn't work either. Can anyone help?

I found a solution that works for me:
/**
 * form action
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function formAction(): void
{
    DebuggerUtility::var_dump($this->request->getParsedBody()['tx_myext_plugin']['order']['firstName']);
}

